# How can I remove the length variables in my recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following code:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String ... args){
    String str = "ABCDE";
    testRecur(str, 1);
  }

  private static void testRecur(String str, int subLength){
    if(subLength > str.length())
      return;

    System.out.println("");
    recuAlgo(str, subLength);
    testRecur(str, ++subLength);
    return;
  }

  private static void recuAlgo(String str, int subLength){
    if(subLength > str.length())
      return;

    System.out.print(str.substring(0, subLength) + " ");
    recuAlgo(str.substring(1, str.length()), subLength);
    return;
  }
}
```

The desired output is:

```
A B C D E 
AB BC CD DE 
ABC BCD CDE 
ABCD BCDE 
ABCDE
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write the recursion without using the string lengths as method inputs.  I adopted the recursion out of two for loops, but I still couldn't get the length out of the method declaration.

How can I remove the `subLength` variables from my recursion?  Or in general what is a better way to solve this problem recursively?

Comment: What do you mean by removing `subLength` from recursion?

Comment: My method definitions both contain the subLength variable, but I would rather not have to pass around an arbitrary length, I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution to this problem then what I've came up with.

Comment: If it's implemented procedurally it would be a nested loop. The `subLength` would mean the index of the outer loop. I don't think you could eliminate this parameter.

Comment: Recursive functions are usually functional. If you can't figure something out by looking at the arguments you need it supplied. E.g. you don't need the string length supplied because you can get that from the string, but there is no way to estimate subLength.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe my entire approach to the problem is wrong then.  There has got to be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why does there have to be a "cleaner solution"?  This looks minimal to me.